# Plotting with rapids cuGraph

Tags: python, rapids

Am quite a latecomer to RAPIDS API. My question is, does the cuGraph package help in plotting similar graphs as those we do with seaborn and matplotlib eg histograms and barcharts?

I have searched everywhere in the internet but I cant get close to this.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[cuGraph](https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/) is a library for graph analytics, not visualization. Think [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) rather than bar charts.

There are many visualization libraries that include GPU support, including Plotly Dash, Bokeh, Datashader, HoloViews, and cuxfilter.